# strtok() C-Strings to Array

Tags: c, arrays, fgets, eof, strtok

Currently learning C, Having some trouble with passing c-string tokens into array.  Lines come in by standard input, strtok is used to split the line up, and I want to put each into an array properly.  an EOF check is required for exiting the input stream.  Here's what I have, set up so that it will print the tokens back to me (these tokens will be converted to ASCII in a different code segment, just trying to get this part to work first).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char string[1024]; //Initialize a char array of 1024 (input limit)

  char *token;
  char *token_arr[1024]; //array to store tokens.
  char *out; //used
  int count = 0;

  while(fgets(string, 1023, stdin) != NULL) //Read lines from standard input until EOF is detected.
  {
    if (count == 0)
      token = strtok(string, " \n"); //If first loop, Get the first token of current input

    while (token != NULL) //read tokens into the array and increment the counter until all tokens are stored
    {
      token_arr[count] = token;
      count++;
      token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    printf("%s\n", token_arr[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

this seems like proper logic to me, but then i'm still learning.  The issue seems to be with streaming in multiple lines before sending the EOF signal with ctrl-D.

For example, given an input of:

`this line will be fine`

the program returns:

`this
line
will
be
fine`

But if given:

`none of this`

`is going to work`

It returns:

`is going to work`

`ing to work`

`to work`

any help is greatly appreciated.  I'll keep working at it in the meantime.

Comment: Eugh. Don't use strtok. Use strsep. If you don't have strsep, write your own strsep. Strtok is the worst function ever written. (direct quote from Brian Kernighan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. You never call `token = strtok(string, " \n");` again once the string is "reset" to a new value, so `strtok()` still thinks it is tokenizing your original string.
2. `strtok` is returning pointers to "substrings" inside `string`. You are changing the contents of what is in `string` and so your second line effectively corrupts your first (since the original contents of `string` are overwritten).

To do what you want you need to either read each line into a different buffer or duplicate the strings returned by `strtok` (`strdup()` is one way - just remember to `free()` each copy...)

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction.  I ended up passing the input to a buffer and using strcat to build the full string before even starting to tokenize.  works like a charm now!